# Movielens Data Set Classification By SVM Algorithm

Tags: matlab, dataset, classification, svm

I want implement a recommender system by Matlab, I choose MoveiLens Dataset , and svm algorithm.
I implement a function that returns two sets of Items. The first set is items that user Rate them more than 3 and second set is items that user Rate less than 4.
Rate is a matrix with 3 column, the first one is user Id,second one is Item Id, and third one is User Rate to this item .

```
  function [like,dislike]=UsetLike(User,Rate)
    k1=1;
    k2=1;
    for i=1:size(Rate,1)
    if(Rate(i,1)==User)
      if(Rate(i,3)>3)
          like(k1)= Rate(i,2);
          k1=k1+1;
      end
      if(Rate(i,3)<=3)
          dislike(k2)= Rate(i,2);
          k2=k2+1;
      end

   end
  end

end
```

Then  I write another function that train by svm such as this.
Feature is a matrix that in (i) row shows item (i) features, that has 19 features with 0 or 1 value.

```
function [svmModel]=TrainSVM(like,dislike,Feture)
group1=zeros(size(like,2),19);
group2=zeros(size(dislike,2),19);
for i=1: size(group1,1)
    group1(i,:)= Feture(like(i),:);
 end
 for i=1: size(group2,1)
    group2(i,:)= Feture(dislike(i),:);
 end
   Dataset=cat(1,group1,group2);

   group=[repmat({'like'},1,size(group1,1)) repmat({'dislike'},1,size(group2,1) )]'; 

   svmModel = svmtrain(Dataset, group, ...
   'Autoscale',true, 'Showplot',false, 'Method','QP', ...
   'BoxConstraint',2e-1, 'Kernel_Function','rbf', 'RBF_Sigma',1);

end
```

Now I want to know if my solution is right? As it was in mostly 3D space I can not precept it. What if I want to use Rate (1-5) instead of like or dislike?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Rates (1-5) as an output signal you will need a modification called **ranking SVM**, as this is not just a multilabel classification, but rather a ranking problem.